# What are the steps to configure SSL for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I am little bit confused about configuring SSL for Tomcat on my local computer. First of all, should I need to create a new keystore with keytool? And then should I import existing.pfx certicate file to that newly create java keystore(.jks file)? And finally export a new blabla.pfx file and add a new Connector which runs on 443 port like below:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="C:/dev/certificates/blabla.pfx" keystorePass="12345" 
keystoreType="PKCS12" maxThreads="25" port="443"   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
scheme="https" secure="true"` sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

What is cacerts? Should I also create a new cacerts file and adding it to the local server? Should I need to do something to make it trusted? Can you please explain the right and necessary order for adding existing certificate to local Tomcat.
Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by Java server?

Comment: @mentallurg tomcat server

Comment: A totally different suggestion: put a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat and let that do the SSL stuff

Comment: The steps for configuring SSL for Tomcst are clearly documented.

Answer (score 1):

It depends... It depends on your goal (do you want to configure it as similar to production as possible? do you want to consider performance?) and on what you have (e.g. does your JRE support TLS 1.3?)

I would assume that you just want to get SSL / TLS with as simple configuration as possible and that at this stage you don't want to care much about security (which is quite OK in many scenarios).

You said there is an existing .pfx certicate. I assume it is a self signed certificate. Then this is all what you need. You don't need any further import, export, conversion.

The configuration format you used is deprecated. I'd suggest you to use  and .

Your configuration can look as follows:

```
    <Connector
            port="443"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            maxThreads="25"
            SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate
                    certificateKeystoreFile=".../your_existing_localhost.pfx"
                    certificateKeystorePassword="12345"
                    type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

This asumes that the .pfx contains a single certificate. In case yoiu have multiple certificates in the same .pfx file, you should specify the alias of the certificate that Tomcat should use:

```
    <Connector
            port="443"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            maxThreads="25"
            SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate
                    certificateKeystoreFile=".../your_existing_localhost.pfx"
                    certificateKeyAlias="your_certificate_alias"
                    certificateKeystorePassword="12345"
                    type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Keeping private key in the same store as certificate is not the best practice. You can put your certificate to one file (which is not protected and easily accessable)
and the private key to another (encrypted and protected with password). Then configuration would look as follows:

```
    <Connector
            port="443"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            maxThreads="25"
            SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate
                    certificateFile=".../localhost_certificate.cer"
                    certificateKeyFile=".../localhost_private_key.pkcs8"
                    certificateKeyPassword="56789"
                    type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Files refered as "cacerts" contain certificates of certification authorities whome you trust. If you deploy some application on Tomcat and this application will access some other server via SSL/TLS, then you will need to establish trust to that external server. Then you will need to register the certificate of that server in your "cacerts" store (or the certificate of some of the "upstream" CA who issued it). But in your case - when you just want to access your Tomcat via SSL/TLS - it is not necessary.

To your question "Should I need to do something to make it trusted?" To make it trusted *to whome?*: To your browser that you run on the same host? To browsers that your run on other hosts (computers, smartphones, other devices) in your local network? You cannot force clients to trust your self-signed certificate. If users in your local network access your Tomcat via HTTPS, every user will have to explicitly add an exception for your self-signed certificate. To make your Tomcat *automatically* trusted for browsers that you run *on the same host*, you can try *mkcert*. To make your Tomcat *automatically* trusted for browsers that access your Tomcat from *other hosts*, you would need to put your Tomcat to the public Internet, register a domain name, get a certificate for this domain from some trusted CA, and access your Tomcat via public Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one step, without needing to use keytool, using [this web-based tool](https://github.com/chiralsoftware/CertWeb) which generates the private key, creates the CSR, imports the fullchain, saves it all as a keystore file (P12 format now), and shows the correct connector for it.